# SharedPreferences not working (android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@4103cd78"

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to pass a score integer between *MathActivity* and *ScoreActivity*. In *ScoreActivity* where the score is to be displayed, it says *Score: android.app.SharedPrefencesImpl@4103cd78*. I'm guessing that my SharedPreferences isn't correctly setup?

**MathActivity**

```
public class MathActivity extends Activity {

public static final String SAVED_DATA = "savedData";

private int SCORE = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_math);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_DATA,MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("SCORE", SCORE);
    editor.commit();
```

**ScoreActivity**

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity {

public static final String SAVED_DATA = "savedData";

private int SCORE = 0; 

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_DATA,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SCORE = preferences.getInt("SCORE", SCORE);


    TextView tvScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvscore);
    tvScore.setText("Score: " + preferences);
```

Comment: but where you set a value to your share pre?

Comment: @SimplePlan I'm new to this so I'm not sure if my SharedPreferences are correctly setup? If you mean the SCORE integer value, it's setup in the MathActivity upon correct answer.
`SCORE++;
                 tvScore.setText("Poäng: " + SCORE);`

Comment: I think it's good practice to use `SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SAVED_DATA,MODE_PRIVATE);`. Well this is not related to the question you asked, just thought of sharing the info.

Comment: @Aniruddha Thank you! I'm new to this so I'm thankful for any tips I get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your score is retrieved from `perferences` and stored in `SCORE`.

See: `SCORE = preferences.getInt("SCORE", SCORE)`

Change:

```
vScore.setText("Score: " + preferences);
```

to

```
vScore.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(SCORE));
```

(Also don't use ALL CAPS for variable names, those are usily used for contants)

Comment: If I make that change, I get an error message saying *Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int*?

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```
tvScore.setText("Score: " + preferences);
```

to

```
tvScore.setText("Score: " + SCORE );
```